# One row of divs with ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a list of divs as looking like below sample:
[image]

I'm using Bootstrap grid system and augularjs. I create divs dynamically, using angularjs ng-repeat directive.

What I want is an endless list of divs containing attribute 'class"col-md-2"' inside a div containing attribute 'class"col-md-12"'. Then I want to use a scrollbar to scroll all the divs in the outer div.

Example code:

```
    <div class="col-md-12" scrollablebar>
        <div ng-repeat="newview in newviewslist" class="col-md-2">
            Here goes the date from newview... 
        </div>
    </div>
```

This doesn't work and "off course" is creating new rows each time ng-repeat is creating a div.

How do I prevent that from happen?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11" scrollablehorizontal>
        <table class="borderless">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="newviews in newviews" valign="top" class="shadowbox" scrollableverticall>
                        <p>
                            all the things... 
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in a col-md-12, there can be 6 x col-md-2 after that there is a linebreak.

try to change "col-md-12" to "row-fluid"

```
<div class="row-fluid" scrollablebar>
    <div ng-repeat="newview in newviewslist" class="col-md-2">
        Here goes the date from newview... 
    </div>
</div>
```

and add css:

```
.row-fluid{
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.row-fluid .col-md-2{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21089/)

Comment: I still get the linebreak after 4 reputations using row-fluid and the col-lg-3 example.

Comment: have you remove the class: col-md-12? and add display: inline-block for the class .col-md-2

Comment: Yes. I dont know if it inherit parents??

Comment: No output at all.. I tried to insert your code outside the rest of my code, and I still dont get and output from the array..

Comment: check the array, remove "newview in newviewslist" and add for testing "n in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']"

Comment: I have already tried that. No output at all.. I copied your jsfiddle example, and within my code it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: try to remove  scrollablebar , and check the console